# How to show two Textview with ellipsize end in horizontal Linearlayout in android?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I am facing one problem which is, I have two Textview in one horizontal Linearlayout and one Textview with ellipsize end and When I have type text more content then it display "..." in Textview ending,  But at that time I can not show the second TextView.

Below Images.
[image]

[image]

But I want to both Textview. If First Textview is with more content then it display ellipsize end and also display second Textview.

Below Image.
  [image]
My Xml Layout is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_profile_photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/editText"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="(20)"
                            android:textSize="12sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Yesterday"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="This is Demo for Just Testing and Its only Demo for Testing."
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_next" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Please share me idea.
Thanks

Comment: Please share me some code. xml particularly.

Comment: please post you xml layout

Comment: your idea is not clear, plz share some code so we can guide u properly.

Comment: @Reena use weights approach for that https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: @Reena Refer my answer i have checked it and it is working.

Comment: instead of horizontal ,take vertical for text view ABC ABC & This is just demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Give a `Weight` to your First Child `Text View` not Second. You not need to use any Fixed width with this.
>
> Just give `android:layout_weight="1"` to First child `Text View` only.

**Refer this.**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC...(20)"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="(20)"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 1:**

> I have made it work for small content also. I have removed Nested `Linear Layouts` which is bad for performance. I have applied changes to your `Layout` please replace this with your `XML`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_profile_photo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="0.90">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.90"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="ABCABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC...(20)"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_name"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="(20)"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Yesterday"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/desc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="This is Demo for Just Testing and Its only Demo for Testing."
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Never use `Nested Linear Layouts` because it is bad for Performance.

Comment: But If i witting only ABC then it will be display ABC            (20) and I want to If i write only ABC then it will be display ABC (20).

Comment: No It is not work properly for less content. If I am writting more content means "ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC "then It is work Properly but I am writting only one time ABC then It is display ABC                   (20) but I want to ABC (20)

Comment: you can check only write ABC then It will be display ABC   bbbbbbbbbbbbb                                   (20) and I want to ABC (20)

Comment: Yes it is fine working with ABC (20) and ABc ABC ABcA BAC ABc ABc ABc...(20)  but It is problem with yesterday String because it is not display if I can writting more content in TextView. you can also check it

Comment: @Reena Please refer **EDIT 1** itself again. Replace code in your XML as i have in my answer. Let me know if you have any problem. It is working like your thoughts now :).

Comment: @Reena Let me know is it worked for you ? if worked then please accept and up-vote my answer thanks :).I think it is working for sure :).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked perfectl. Thanks a lot once again

Comment: @Reena Glad it worked Cheers ! Let me know if you have any other problem :).

Comment: sure. Thanks once again

Comment: how to set desc textview fill in match_parent? It is display only till below (20). But i want to disp Textview is display in full textview. please see my screenshot in my question

Comment: @Reena Please continue in chat.

Comment: When changed the weight from 0dp to wrap_content, the alignment is gone for a toss..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLength="25"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:text="rtert"
        android:textSize="@dimen/common_text_label" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="rtyrty"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/common_text_label"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Kinjal Jain Please check 1st screen shot. If I want to only ABC name in first TextView then It will Display ABC (20)

Comment: in which linear layout you put your both textview 1. in linear layout layout_weight =2    2. in both text view put weight = 1

Answer (score 0):

use `weight sum` for your `ellipsize` `text view` so it will always give space for second `textview`.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:text="this is for checking that ellipsize is working or not in the view"/>

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="20"
               />

        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: If I take fixed width then it is cause problem in different sizes devices.

Comment: this is just snippet you can add matchparent  or wrap content if you want because i can see weight_sum for your parent layout also . so change width and check. @Reena

Comment: its not possible for fixed size because it is problematic in another different sizes

Comment: i get it just put your width whatever you define like match parent or wrap content or size and check . you have  android:layout_width="match_parent" so put match parent and check. for parent layout that is your linear layout. @Reena

Answer (score 0):

i just added only two `TextView` according to your design set

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_timeline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="This is Demo for Just Testing and Its only Demo for Testing."
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem, just copy and past with you,

```
         <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="5dp" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC...(20)"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/editText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:text="(20)"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Yesterday"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="This is Demo for Just Testing and Its only Demo for Testing."
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

if this solve your problem please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @Reena if you are still getting issue then let me know i will guide you.